# Change CSS background image position of DIV from a separate link MOUSEOVER?

Tags: mouseover

Is it possible to change CSS position of a background image with a DIV ("omega") from a separate link ("alpha") with a MOUSEOVER?

```
<a class="omega" href="#"></a>

<div id="alpha"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is JavaScript/jQuery ok?  If so, something like this should work:

```
$('.omega').hover(function(){
    $('#alpha').css('backgroundPosition', '500px 150px');
}, function(){
    $('#alpha').css('backgroundPosition', '0px 0px');
});
```

The first function is for mouseover, the second one resets it when the mouse leaves.  Admittedly, I haven't tried this, but in theory it should work.  See [jquery hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [jquery css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for more info.